# Normal distribution and probabilities

Tags: statistics

If $Z~N(0,1^2)$ and I wanted to find $P(Z<2$, I could compute it on my calculator as $0.477...$. and if I wanted to find P(Z>1), I could compute it as $0.1586$. Now say I wanted to find $P(1 < Z < 2)$, I would get $0.139$. Now my question is, why can't I do
$P(Z>1)$ $*$ $P(Z<2)$ to get the correct answer of $0.139$?

Comment: Because the events $Z>1$ and $Z<2$ are not independent.

Comment: I thought that but could you provide some intuition on how they aren't?

Comment: @ArkPlYee $Z$ is not independent from $Z$. Let Z the r. v. of a fair die. Then $P(Z >3 \cap Z <6)=P(Z >3 | Z <6)\cdot ( Z <6)=\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{5}{6}=\frac{1}{3} \neq P(Z >3 )\cdot ( Z <6) = \frac{3}{6}\cdot  \frac{5}{6}  $

Comment: My calculator says $P(Z\le 2) \approx 0.9772$ and $P(Z\le 1)\approx 0.8413$ so by subtraction $P(1 \lt Z \le 2)= P(Z\le 2)-P(Z\le 1)\approx 0.1359$.